# how to add a button for create new file in NSOpenPanel?(not create folder button)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsopenpanel

macOS：how to add a button for creating new file in a NSOpenPanel?(not create folder button)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `NSOpenPanel`'s `accessoryView` property, which you can use to add arbitrary buttons and other UI elements to the open panel.

Comment: The accessory view would display on top of the buttons though, right? Is there a way you can add custom buttons to that bar? E.g: I see an `Options` button when opening a new file in TextEdit

Comment: Were you able to find out, how to do that?